# Android Thread Join

Tags: android, multithreading, join

in my code I have a code inside a thread that first tries to update something from Database and if the update is not successful then an insert is tried. My problem is that this code is called twice (it's not ok I know but let's ignore this for now) and because of this the insert is called twice because the update is not finished (at least this is what I think). I searched on  google I thought to use `thread.join()`. My question is if it's ok to use `thread.join()` in my case.

Thanks

```
 public void persistChangesToDatabase() {

    final Thread backThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                try {

                    openDataBase();

                     <-- SOME CODE -->

                    //First, an UPDATE is tried
                    int rowsAffected = updateTable();

                    // If update fails an INSERT is tried
                    if (rowsAffected == 0) {

                        //Insert
                        insert();
                    } 

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                       
                }
            }

    });
    backThread.start();
    try {
        backThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: It is recommended to use AsynTask instead of threads for more control of their execution.

Comment: I know but now I want to resolve the problem for this method. Can anyone help me?